# RecognitionListener is getting ignored

Tags: java, android

In the background of my application, I would like to use speech recognition. The goal is to say "Hey app" and the app should be listening to what I say and return a string. So basically the same as Google Assistant.

So to run that app in the background, I have created this service class:

```java
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class SttService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println("I am running!");

        SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SttListener());

        Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        startActivity(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("A sign");
        return null;
    }

    protected class SttListener implements RecognitionListener {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            System.out.println("A sign");
        }
    }
}
```

So I see that the service is running since I get the message "I am running!" but nothing else happens. So in that case my intent and my class `SttListener` are not doing anything.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement RecognitionListener to your service with

```
public class SttService extends Service implements RecognitionListener
```

and override neccecary methods. And then set recognitionListener to your service;

```
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
```

You will see "A sign" message from your system.

Comment: I tried the same but still not seeing that message.

Comment: Maybe you didin't get necessary permissions